# Should we use backend code or Client side code for e-commerce android app

Tags: android, database, lambda, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an android e-commerce app and recently I'm having little doubts on some concepts.
Should I include my functions in the client side apk or on the online servers (like Google functions, Amazon lambda)?

For example an user adds an item in his cart
Should I include my code in the client side apk like:

```
Get the item's price and multiply it with the quantity and then add to the total price of cart.
```

Or should I just send the data from the client side apk like:

```
Send the unique ID and quantity to the specific function in online functions
```

And then put the multiplying and stuff... in the online functions.

Where should I include these calculations?

Answer (score 2):

I think the important thing here is how you're managing state. When the user adds something to their cart, does the app tell the server they've done that? Do they have a cart on the server, with a list of what that user has added so far? Or does it all happen on the user's device, and the server doesn't know anything about the cart until they go to check out?

If the cart is managed on the server, I'd say it's better to let that handle all of the state, and let it tell the device what to display. If the user adds 2 items, tell the server what they've added, and the server can say "your cart contains this" and include the price in that information. It gives you more control, because your server is the source of truth - you're not relying on the device to get it right (which sounds silly but a lot of weird things can happen)

Whatever you do though, **don't** let the user's device tell the server how much the items cost! If it's calculating the total for the user then fine, so long as it's for display purposes. But when it comes to calculating how much the items cost at checkout, you do that yourself, server-side - take item IDs and counts from the user, nothing else. If they fake a request that says 50 gold watches for $1, you'll be in big trouble!

That might be obvious but I had to put it out there just in case!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're calling that function from. If you're calling that function from somewhere in your front end code, you should include it in your client. If you're calling the function from somewhere in one of your Lambda or Google functions, then you should put it there.

The concept that you might want to learn about is called scope. Wherever a function is in scope, some thing else can call it. You might consider looking up the rules for scope in your specific programming language.